# Taking Video or still pictures from the same button using Android Camera Intent

Tags: android, video, camera, image

I am developing an app for only the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.  I have a button that opens the default camera app on the tablet using:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

The default app has a sliding button that normally allows you to switch to video but it is disabled.  Now, they want to be able to slide that button and take video as well.  According to Android at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents they make it seem like I would actually have to have two separate buttons in my layout, one to capture the video, and one to capture still images.  Is there a way to just open the camera and then let the user decide if they want video or images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify if you want to grab a video or a picture. This is necessary because before you call the intent you must set the filename of the future image/video.